# Incorrect calculation result in Javascript

Tags: javascript

My Javascript formula is

```
total = parseFloat(unit * rate) + 
        parseFloat(rateamount) + 
        parseFloat(((unit * rate) + 
        (rateamount)) * (tax/100));
```

values are:

`unit = 5`, `rate = 10`, `rateamount = 10`, `tax = 10`.

The answer it is giving me is `561`, which is wrong.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it, or calculate the formula with hand?

Comment: yes by hand the answer is 66

Comment: Using that exact formula I don't get 561, I get 66.

Comment: What's with all the parseFloats? Parse your input as float before the calculation, when assigning them to variables.

Comment: (your code doesn't have the error you're saying)

Comment: this `parseFloat(5 * 10) + parseFloat(10) + parseFloat(((5 * 10) + (10)) * (10/100));` outputs `66`

Comment: I also get 66 not 561

Comment: this however will output `561`:`total = parseFloat('5' * '10') + parseFloat('10') + parseFloat((('5' * '10') + ('10')) * ('10'/100));`

Comment: could you place a breakpoint on this line and verify that all your variables are exactly the same you wrote, cause result is truly 66 here. Or somebody messed around with overriding parseFloat function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are concatenating strings with this part:

```
parseFloat(((unit * rate) + (rateamount))
```

You forgot to parse `rateamount` which is a string of `'10'`.

So this Code:

```js
var unit = '5',
  rate = '10',
  rateamount = '10',
  tax = '10';

var total = parseFloat(unit * rate) + parseFloat(rateamount) + parseFloat(((unit * rate) + (rateamount)) * (tax / 100));
console.log(total);
```

should be like that:

```js
var unit = '5',
  rate = '10',
  rateamount = '10',
  tax = '10'

var total = parseFloat(unit * rate) + parseFloat(rateamount) + parseFloat(((unit * rate) + parseFloat(rateamount)) * (tax / 100));
console.log(total);
```

Though i wouldn't use `parseFloat` like that, i would just do it once before any calculations, in order to stay away from bugs like this one.

```js
var unit = '5',
  rate = '10',
  rateamount = '10',
  tax = '10';

var parsedUnit = parseFloat(unit),
  parseRate = parseFloat(rate),
  parsedRateamount = parseFloat(rateamount),
  parsedTax = parseFloat(tax);

var total = parsedUnit * parseRate + parsedRateamount + ((parsedUnit * parseRate) + (parsedRateamount)) * (parsedTax / 100);
console.log(total);
```

Comment: This is another calculation which works perfectly for me, but when I use the above formula it does not work.                       total = parseFloat(unit * rate) + parseFloat(unit * rate * rateamount)+parseFloat(((unit * rate) + (unit * rate * rateamount)) * (tax/100));

Comment: As i mentioned, you forgot to use `parseFloat` on `rateamount`. this is why you should do it once and store it as a new variable so you wouldn't have to repeat it over and over in one line of code.